# fail2ban iptables returned 200, iptables 0 references

Tags: fail2ban

I installed fail2ban but on start I got multiple error messages:

iptables -n -L gives me 0 references for each jail. (should be 1?)

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain fail2ban-apache-auth (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-badbots (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-apache-nokiddies (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain fail2ban-php-url-fopen (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Also I m getting error messages like:

```
fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -N fail2ban-ssh
iptables -A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
iptables -I <known/chain> -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j fail2ban-ssh returned 200
2022-04-30 14:25:10,428 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'skinlou_x' started
2022-04-30 14:25:10,429 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'apache-auth' started
2022-04-30 14:25:10,430 fail2ban.actions.action: ERROR  iptables -N fail2ban-php-url-fopen
iptables -A fail2ban-php-url-fopen -j RETURN
```

I tried to reinstall fail2ban but it is always same. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `iptables -I <known/chain> -p tcp -m multiport --dports ssh -j fail2ban-ssh returned 200`

Normally `<known/chain>` would be replaced by `INPUT` or something similar.

Which banning action is configured there? Is it some custom action (or is there some `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/*.local` file overwriting some setting)?

Otherwise it looks like versions conflict to me. Are you trying to use some new config files with older fail2ban version?
Anyway to do full reinstall, save your configuration `/etc/fail2ban`, uninstall fail2ban, remove `/etc/fail2ban`, install fail2ban and try to restore your local jail configuration in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` from your backup.

Also note https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-to-install-or-upgrade-fail2ban-manually

By the way, I wonder why your iptables chains are called `fail2ban-*` whether fail2ban, already since some v.0.9 version, uses `f2b-*` names for the chains.

Which fail2ban version is it?

Comment: hi, thank you it was probably a version conflict. I removed all files and uninstalled fail2ban and then manually installed newer version. The older one was 0.8